# How to validate or wrap user inputted HTML to fix unclosed tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have text boxes in a form where users can input formatted text or raw HTML. It all works fine, however is a user doesn't close a tag (like a bold tag), then it ruins all HTML formatting after it (it all becomes bold).

Is there a way to either validate the user's input, automatically close tags, or somehow wrap the user input in an element to stop it leaking over?

Comment: May be try with `escapeSpecialChars()` js function?

Comment: Is the user's input only displayed to **them**, or do you store it and display it to *other* users as well?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Stored and displayed to others.

Comment: @PeterR: Than **no** client-side solution is safe, you need to go with full sanitization, which is non-trivial. You haven't mentioned what server-side tech you use, but there's some form of HTML sanitizer for just about every dev stack.

Answer (score 2):

You may try [jquery-clean](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/)

```
$.htmlClean($myContent);
```

Comment: this is an amazing plugin. hopefully, it doesn't have any issues. Thanks @ Matei Mihai

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to either validate the user's input, automatically close tags, or somehow wrap the user input in an element to stop it leaking over?

Yes: When the user is done editing the text area, you can parse what they've written using the browser, then get an HTML version of the *parsed result* from the browser:

```
var div = $("<div>");
div.html($("#the-textarea").val());
var html = div.html();
```

Live example — type an unclosed tag in and click the button:

```js
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
    var div = $("<div>");
    div.html($("#the-textarea").val());
    var html = div.html();
    $(document.body).append("<p>You wrote:</p><hr>" + html + "<hr>End of what you wrote.");
});
```

```html
<p>Type something unclosed here:</p>
<textarea id="the-textarea" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
<br><input type="button" value="Click when ready">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Important Note**: If you're going to store what they write and then display it to *anyone else*, there is **no** client-side solution, including the above, which is safe. Instead, you must use a server-side solution to "sanitize" the HTML you get from them, to remove (for instance) malicious content, etc. All the above does is help you get mostly-well-formed markup, not *safe* markup.

Even if you're just displaying it to them, it would still be best to sanitize it, since they can work around any client-side pre-processing you do.

Comment: This works great. And it can be shortened to `resultHTML = $("<div>").html(foobar).html();`

Comment: @Flimm - Yes. I tend to keep things separate in answers to emphasize the steps, but as you say, you can combine things a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use : http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/ .

But if the user is entering the html by hand you could just check to have all tags closed properly. If not, just display an error message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jQuery element using the text and then get it's html, like so

**Sample**

```
<textarea>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>some content</span>
            <span>some content
    </div>
</textarea>
```

**Script**

```
alert($($('textarea').text()).html());
```

---

```js
alert($($('textarea').text()).html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>some content</span>
      <span>some content
        </div>
      </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to check if entered HTML is actually valid and parseable by browser is to let browser try it out itself using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML). Then you could check if result is ok or not:

```js
function checkHTML(html) {
    var dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/xml");
    return dom.documentElement.childNodes[0].nodeName !== 'parsererror';
}

$('button').click(function() {
    var html = $('textarea').val();
    var isValid = checkHTML(html);console.log(isValid)
    $('div').html(isValid ? html : 'HTML is not valid!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="80" rows="7">&lt;div&gt;Some HTML</textarea> <button style="vertical-align:top">Check</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I'd say the odds of end users entering valid **XML** are fairly low. Professional web developers found it so challenging that XHTML failed. :-)